# How can I have a sidekick/squire?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, npc, sidekick

In [*Mutants & Masterminds*](http://www.mutantsandmasterminds.com/), you can purchase a [sidekick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidekick) as a feat.

I'm rolling up a knight, and I want a squire, using a similar game mechanic.

Is there anything like this in D&D, other than the [Leadership](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#leadership) feat? I don't want a small gang of cohorts, but only one follower.

Or would this just be a 'the GM rolls them up as an NPC and you wing it' kind of thing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually, the Leadership feat would work well for this. Leadership grants a cohort (a single high level follower) and followers (several low level ones). You could take the cohort and simply never claim the low-level followers.

Comment: Agreed, Leadership lets you have a sidekick/cohort of up to your level minus two, which is not colossally different from the M&M Sidekick feat (in M&M 1e, that is, which is all I have) - which caps them at your level-1. I guess you could try to talk your DM into cashing in all the followers for that one additional level of cohort.

Comment: I would go so far as to say that this is exactly the sort of thing Leadership was designed for.

Comment: There is also the Improved Cohort feat from *Heroes of Battle* I think.  It allows your Cohort to be level -1 instead of level -2.  You're still allowed followers.

Answer (score 4):

If you want something other than the Leadership feat. In DMGII there are two feats that you can use :

> Apprentice : A character with this feat has apprenticed himself to a master in order to speed his learning and bolster his skills.

and

> Mentor : A character who takes this feat has offered his knowledge and skill to a lower-level NPC and takes that NPC on as an apprentice.

Another way of getting a side-kick is to use *charm person* or *dominate person*, but considering this is Knight you are talking about, that may not be the best way.

Comment: Oooh! Knight Thrallherd. "Hi, I'm Sir Dominator, and this is Squire 43."

Answer (score 3):

I'm not trying to be the "just roleplay it!" guy, because that guy is annoying, but my feeling is that you could certainly pick up a squire or other cohort purely through roleplay.

But there would be a core difference, in games I run.  Spend a feat on Leadership, and you'll get a cohort who is absolutely trustworthy and will never betray you.  Pick up a squire through roleplay, and get a guy who you're pretty sure you can trust, but who is likely to have priorities that don't entirely match your own.

Comment: I believe the rules do support this (although I don't have them handy). The catch is that a non-leadership cohort takes a share of the XP for each encounter they participate in, and expects to be paid (usually with a half share of treasure).

Comment: @AceCalhoon A leadership cohort also expects to be paid. The experience point thing is handy, though.

Answer (score -1):

Best for this as has been said but why not make it even more suited to a knight?  Squire sure.  Why not a trusted war horse, or hunting dog can think of more..?  All could gain exp with you.  I can think of many more to make your squire stay lower and using leadership to its full potential.  Its possibly one of the best feats open.  Downfall is as a DM I would make you role-play some of your cohorts (or I would play them ...), remember up to DM, and for that matter they may choose one for you.   And best situation a story/session creates one.

Comment: Could you edit this answer? It's quite hard to read, but you may have an interesting idea. Perhaps multiple paragraphs will help.